# Getting the attribute type of any property in an ember-data model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Using a specific instance of a model, is there any way to get the type of any given attribute? For example, say I've got a model called Person. Inside a template, I pass an instance of this model *and a property name* to a helper function. In that function, I want to be able to find out what type of property that is.

The closest thing I've seen is this, straight from the Ember docs:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: attr('string'),
  lastName: attr('string'),
  birthday: attr('date')
});

var attributes = Ember.get(App.Person, 'attributes')

attributes.forEach(function(name, meta) {
  console.log(name, meta);
});

// prints:
// firstName {type: "string", isAttribute: true, options: Object, parentType: function, name: "firstName"}
// lastName {type: "string", isAttribute: true, options: Object, parentType: function, name: "lastName"}
// birthday {type: "date", isAttribute: true, options: Object, parentType: function, name: "birthday"}
```

This *would* work, expect that in my helper method, I don't know the model type. I need to be able to do something like this and have it return the same information:

```
Ember.get(person, 'attributes');
```

Sure, I'd like to do something more like this:

```
person.getMetaInfoFor(property);
```

But that's just wishful thinking at this point. I'm just trying to figure out if some unknown property of some unknown model is a string or a date. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember 2.4+, use [eachAttribute](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_eachAttribute) :

```js
var attributeType

person.eachAttribute(function(name, meta){
    if (name === property){
        attributeType = meta.type
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the type of an property by using JQuery type() function

```
function getMetaInfoFor(input){
  if(jQuery.type( input) === "boolean"){
    return boolean;
   }
 if(jQuery.type( input) === "number"{
   return number;
  }
if(jQuery.type(input) === "date"){
   return date;
  }
};
```

you will need to write a function to convert you input date in custom format as per your requirement.

you can keep adding all types as per this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/)

Comment: That would work, except for things like dates, which are stored as datetime strings.